# My code is supposed to move to a new line and add new customer to the database,its showing error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()   

Dim CustomerNumber As String, FullName As String, ContactNumber As Long,                     CompanyName As String  

Worksheets("CustForm").Select

CustomerNumber = Range("D4")
FullName = Range("D5")

ContactNumber = Range("D6")
CompanyName = Range("D7")

Worksheets("CustomerList").Select
Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("A5").Select

If Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("A5").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
 **Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("A5").End(x1Down).Select**
    (here is where my error points me too)
End If
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = CustomerNumber
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = FullName
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = CompanyName
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = ContactNumber

 Worksheets("CustForm").Select
 Worksheets("CustForm").Visible = True
 Worksheets("OrderInvoice").Activate
 Range("D4:J7").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: it looks like you have `Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("A5").End(x1Down).Select` where you should have `Worksheets("CustomerList").Range("A5").End(xlDown).Select` (i.e. a 1 where it should be an l)...

Comment: lol...omg it helps to take a break from codingg when you stuck. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to improve upon your code.  I've rewritten the functionality below and avoided the use of `.Select` and `.Activate` as it's not recommended to use these.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim CustomerNumber As String, FullName As String, ContactNumber As Long, CompanyName As String
Dim wsForm As Worksheet: Set wsForm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustForm")
Dim wsList As Worksheet: Set wsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerList")
Dim firstEmptyRow As Long

With wsList
    firstEmptyRow = wsList.Cells(wsList.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & firstEmptyRow) = wsForm.Range("D4")
    .Range("B" & firstEmptyRow) = wsForm.Range("D5")
    .Range("C" & firstEmptyRow) = wsForm.Range("D7")
    .Range("D" & firstEmptyRow) = wsForm.Range("D6")
End With

Worksheets("OrderInvoice").Range("D4:J7").ClearContents
End Sub
```

This code should do exactly the same as you have in your original function, but as you can see it's a lot shorter, neater and tidier.  Let me know if there is any aspect of the code above you don't understand and I'll explain it if you need it.